# How to show php file output in span by document write?

Tags: javascript, php

My JavaScript code inserts values into a database.

I want to:

- echo some value in `insert.php` file, and
- show the results in above `span` by `document.write()`.

  - preferable a text link or image link.

What amendment do I need to make to `insert.php` to do so?

```
<script language="JavaScript" >
        var bhs = document.createElement('script');
        var bhs_id = "yvw3lwc1tnvq670ybzprm8xyh93rider";
        bhs.src = "//online.examaim.com/insert.php?site=" + bhs_id + ""; 
        document.head.appendChild(bhs);
document.write("<span id='o_" + bhs_id + "'></span>");
    </script>
```

Comment: Which do you need help with - the PHP side or the Javascript side?

Comment: whichever is needed to achieve the desired results as described below

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide more of an explanation as to what you are trying to achieve? It sounds like you might be confused as to how php works but to do specifically what you are asking:

```
document.write("<span id='o_" + <?php echo $someVariable ?> + "'></span>");
```

but I am guessing that the file with this javascript in is not insert.php?

You link to php files the same way you link to a html file. I think there may be a fundamental misunderstanding on how php works here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/

Comment: Sir i place above javascript code on a website. this script collects data and send to that insert.php file. Besides i want to show variable value created from insert.php corresponding to a bhs id on that website where javascript code is placed.